# Incorrect value when getting specific digits from number

Tags: c, math, cs50

My output seems not to match my (tested) calculations.

```
const char* credit_card(void) {
    long card = get_card();
    PRINT_VAL(card); //prints value to console

    if(checksum(card)) {

        int cardlen = log10(card)+1; //gets length of card
        int left = card % (long) pow(10, log10(card)); //should give first digit
        PRINT_VAL(left);

        int left_two = card % (long) pow(10, (log10(card)-1)); //should give 1st 2 digits
        PRINT_VAL(left_two);

        switch(cardlen) {
            case 13:
            if(left == 4) {return "VISA";}
            return "INVALID visa13";

            case 16:
            if(left == 4) {return "VISA";}

            if(left_two >= 51 && left_two <= 55) {return "MASTERCARD";}
            return "INVALID visa/mst16";

            case 15:
            if(left_two == 34 || left_two == 37) {return "AMEX";}
        }
    }
    return "INVALID - CHECKSUM FAILED";
}
```

Notice what happens when I do some test runs (the last line is printed from `main`)...

### Test 1

```
Enter your card number:
5555555555554444
**val of card: 5555555555554444**
**val of left: 7**
**val of left_two: 14**
Card Type: INVALID foo visa/mst16
```

### Test 2

```
Enter your card number:
4111111111111111
**val of card: 4111111111111111**
**val of left: 3**
**val of left_two: 11**
Card Type: INVALID foo visa/mst16
```

As you can see, it's not returning the correct digits for `left` or `left_two`. I'm not getting correct results for `case 13` or `case 15` either. However, the `left` and `left_two` calculations are giving me the correct results on my calculator. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: do not use floating point operations when dealing with integer numbers

Comment: Are you sure about those calculations?  Ignoring rounding errors, `pow(10, log10(x))` would work out to `x`, and your attempt to find the left digit would always be zero.

Comment: `long card` -  usually long is 32 bits. To store 16 digit integer you need 64 bits.

Comment: @Dmitri How so? 10^log10(5555555555554444) = 5.5 recurring on a calculator

Comment: base 10 log of x is the power you'd have to raise 10 to to get x.  So if you raise 10 to that power, you get the original x.   You're finding the log, then reversing that to get the original number again.  If it shows differently, it's due to the intermediate results being inexact.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland I did initially suspect this to be the issue, but as you can see from the `PRINT_VAL(card)` call, it managed to store the card number inside the `long`

Comment: Logarithms? Powers? It's just string of digits. For card, phone, PIN, house etc numbers, use a string. How are you going to recover leading zeros from an integer?

Comment: @WeatherVane I see, so you’re suggesting that i use a string (or more specifically a `char` array), and then just find `char[0]` and `char[1]`?

Comment: Absolutely: that simplifies the code considerably, IMO you have gone the wrong way. Also, please use `'4'` and not the ASCII value `52`, etc. A "number" does not always mean an integer, and a "character" does not always mean `char` - assumptions which are understandably very easy to make.

Comment: @WeatherVane Many thanks, I appreciate your feedback. I will take this approach now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred implementation would check the digits using the string representation of the card number, as noted in the comments. This would avoid problems related to potential integer overflow, limited precision of floating points, and leading zeros.

The following addresses the issues with OP's code as posted.

> ```
> int cardlen = log10(card)+1; //gets length of card
> ```

The above calculates the number of digits of the card number (assuming 64-bit integers, not counting leading zeros).

> ```
> int left = card % (long) pow(10, log10(card));         //should give first digit
> int left_two = card % (long) pow(10, (log10(card)-1)); //should give 1st 2 digits
> ```

This, however:

- does not use the `cardlen` number of digits previously calculated, so it divides by the wrong number (essentially by `card` for the first one, except for some loss of precision);
- uses the `%` modulus instead of `/` integer division, so it gets trailing instead of leading digits.

The corrected version should be:

```
 int left = card / (long) pow(10, cardlen - 1);      //should give first digit
 int left_two = card / (long) pow(10, cardlen - 2);  //should give 1st 2 digits
```

Comment: Using `log10(card)` is a problem with edge cases near a power of 10 and fails dramatically when `card <= 0`.  Better to use integer math for an integer problem than FP.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Completely right. One should *never* use floating point to solve integer problems that require exact solutions (except maybe some very special cases with extreme care taken). That's part of what the disclaimer at the top was meant to cover. Besides that, however, OP's code had a couple of pure math issues, which the rest of the answer addressed. But the other problems with the approach still remain as noted.